# React Promise stuck on {Pending} Promise Status Fulfilled

Tags: reactjs, promise, axios

I have this get request always returns a Promise {}

```
       const appData = api.get('/applicant/'+userId).then(results => results.data);
        console.log(appData);
```

but when I expand the console log for appData i get the following.

```
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseValue]]: Object
class1: "Hunter"
faction: "Horde"
name: "lkamnsdflkm"
questions: (16) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
server: "Tichondrius"
spec: "BM"
__proto__: Object
```

I've tried formatting the request like this

```
const appData = async () => 
        {
           const data = await api.get('/applicant/'+userId).then(results => results.data);
            return data

        }
```

the return is the same as the original. adding a .catch to it doesn't solve my issues.
I've google'd a lot of different keywords to find an answer

**EDIT:**

```
async getApp(req,res)
    {
        try {
            const app = req.params;
            console.log(app);
            const exists = await App.find({app});
            if(exists)
            {
                const appData = await App.find(app).then(doc => doc);
                //console.log(appData); 
                res.json(appData);
             }
        }   
        catch(error)
        {
            console.log(error);
        }        
    }
```

that the function its calling

**Update**: the pending only occurs in a React Component. Outside of the component in a different class it works fine.

Comment: Can you show the code that runs when you call `api.get`?

Comment: Async functions always return promises. Wrapping api.get in another async function just gives you a different function you'd need to await.

Comment: i have added the function `api.get` is calling

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` will print the promise object using its reference so the fulfilled promise you see could be still pending when you logged it in the first case.

In the second case you are return the promise not the `result.data`

As async functions always return a promise so you should `await` the promise before getting the data

Using `async/await` it would look like:

```js
async function getAppdata() {
  // Here we wait for the promise to be fullfilled before getting `result.data`
  const { data } = await api.get(`/applicant/${userId}`);
  return data;
}

try {
  const appData = await getAppData();
  console.log(appData);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

Using `then/catch`:

```js
api.get(`/applicant/${userId}`)
  .then(result => {
    const appData = result.data;
    console.log(appData);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Comment: doing any of those still just causes the same response.